# Sort a tuple with many condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

For example, I have a tuple:

```
 m = [(5,1),(3,7),(5,7),(6,2),(8,2),(3,6),(5,3),(8,2)]
```

I want to sort this tuple to a tuple like this:

```
 m_sorted = [(8, 2), (8, 2), (6, 2), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 7), (3, 6),
    (3, 7)]
```

First I do:

```
m =  sorted(m,reverse=True)
```

=>  m = [(8, 2), (8, 2), (6, 2), (5, 7), (5, 3), (5, 1), (3, 7), (3, 6)]

But after that i'm stuck, i don't know what to do next.Conditions is sort descending first element in tuple if they duplicate sort ascending second element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way. This assumes you want to sort by the first element (decreasing) and second element (increasing).

```
m = [(5,1),(3,7),(5,7),(6,2),(8,2),(3,6),(5,3),(8,2)]

res = sorted(m, key=lambda x: (-x[0], x[1]))

# [(8, 2), (8, 2), (6, 2), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 7), (3, 6), (3, 7)]
```

This takes advantage of 2 properties:

1. `sorted` has a `key` argument, which accepts an anonymous `lambda` function.
2. In Python, tuples and lists are sorted in element order.

---

As a note, because sorting is stable, you can split this into 2 steps:

```
res_intermediate = sorted(m, key=lambda x: x[1])
res = sorted(res_intermediate, key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Comment: can i replace lambda by a function ? tks

Comment: `lambda` is a function! Of course, yes. You can define a function `def sorter_func(x): .....` and just put `key=sorter_func`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you although not so elegant

```
x = list(reversed(sorted(m)))
x_sorted = []
for i in reversed(sorted(set([i[0] for i in x]))):
    y = [j[1] for j in x if j[0] == i]
    for j in sorted(y): x_sorted.append((i, j))
print(x_sorted)
```

> [(8, 2), (8, 2), (6, 2), (5, 1), (5, 3), (5, 7), (3, 6), (3, 7)]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key parameter of the `sorted` function to do so like this:

```
sorted(m, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]), reverse=True)
```

This works because `tuple`s are sorted lexicographically, each element at a time from left to right. Also, by using the `key` param you can specify a function that returns the values the elements should be sorted by, instead of their actual values.